# magento and solr reindexing issue

Tags: magento, solr, reindex

im having troubles reindexing magento with solr, im getting the following error via ssh (all other indexes successfully:

Error reindexing Solr: Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

any ideas how to fix this?

many thanks

Comment: more details? solrconfig, schema? how you trying to index?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a time limit of 5000 miliseconds where as your solr indexing needs more time.

1. Increase time limit.
2. While indexing is running check solr log using tail commmand.
3. Using Solr interface query solr if some new products or data update in place.
4. Also you can write some log code in sole client.php  adddoc function to check if this is getting called or not.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue... I'm assuming you're using Magento Solarium. I opened an issue on github with the dev, I'll update you if he responds with a solution. In the meanwhile, if you were able to fix it, please let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the only relevant hit from Google considering this issue, I add my findings here. The issue arises when you have a large database of products (or many shops together with many products). I noticed SOLR was filling up until the error occurred, after that the SOLR index was empty. Then I found in the code that the indexing process ends with committing all the changes. This is where the timeout happens.

Just put the timeout settings in `system -> configuration -> catalogus -> Solarium search` to a large number (like 500 seconds), do a total re-index and put back the timeout settings to a more reasonable number (2 seconds).

Though there are 2 options, one for search and a general timeout setting, this doesn't seem to work. If you change the search time out setting it still affects the indexing process.

You don't want to leave the timeout at 500 seconds, this can cause serious issues on your server performance.